# Background fetch on Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, ios, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have been looking around, but I don't see any topics related to background fetch in Xamarin.forms. I have an Xamarin.forms.iOS solution that can update data by just dragging the view down.

How should I go about setting up a background fetch on xamarin.forms (is there such a thing?) or do I have to create a custom renderer for the iOS application?

My main goal is to have the application check for new data every minute or so while using as little resources as possible. I am using azure in case there is some work around to doing this.

Comment: Were you able to implement background fetch in your Xamarin.Forms project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use iOS Background Fetch you will have to implement the fetch code in the iOS project as you normally would.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/#Background_Fetch_iOS_7